# Any idea which software was used to generate these circuit diagrams?

Tags: drawing

[image]

And/or:

[image]

I'm trying to choose a free schematic drawing software, and like the way these two look. I've read related questions about circuit drawing software as well. I like Fritzing, but it lacks some components. For example, I cannot get that RS232 component into it.

Comment: eagle and fritzing.

Comment: @markrages Thanks. I use Fritzing, but it doesn't seem to give me either of those results.

Comment: Hm, what's up with the down vote? People, if you down vote, *please* comment with a reason so that we don't make the same mistake twice.

Comment: First one is Eagle in default colors.  Second looks like fritzing to me, but could be Visio or Inkscape or such.  user submitted parts: http://code.google.com/p/fritzing/issues/detail?id=875

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top diagram is drawn in [Eagle](http://cadsoftusa.com). Eagle is scalable and libraries are freely available. Creating own libraries is also fairly easy.

Second diagram I'm not too sure but it could be drawn using ms-paint. Drawing style is more enthusiastic than professional.